# Permission issue with PHP on Windows share

Tags: php, windows, apache, permissions, fopen

Here's my setup. I've got a linux box running Apache and PHP. I have a folder mounted on my linux box that points to a directory on my windows server where my HTML files are stored. My virtualhosts file points to the mounted folder, so Apache is getting the files from the Windows share.

I'm having some issues with fopen. When I run this:

```
<?php

    echo 'cwd is: ', getcwd(), "<br />\n";
    echo 'target should be: ', getcwd(), "/data.txt <br />\n";
    echo 'file already exists: ', file_exists('data.txt') ? 'yes':'no', "<br />\n";

    $file = fopen("data.txt", "a");
    if ( !$file ) {
      die('fopen failed');
    }
    $c = fwrite($file, "\n$name,$lastname,$email");
    fclose($file);
    echo $c, ' bytes written';
?>
```

I get the following back:

> cwd is: /home/brian/website/googlecalendar/html
>   target should be: /home/brian/website/googlecalendar/html/data.txt
>   file already exists: no
>   Warning: fopen(data.txt): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /home/brian/website/googlecalendar/html/testfopen.php on line 7 fopen failed

On Windows, I've checked the permissions on the "html" folder, and everything is set to allow everyone to write. I'm not sure what else I need to change. It should work, right?

Comment: i have the same issue here :/ did you manage to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi**

**Try**,Change the sub directory and files to be in the group **"www"**

Comment: assuming his apache user is "www"

Comment: I created a new user on my Windows server called "www-data" (since that's the apache user) and gave it all permissions on that folder, but still no luck.